# как использовать css свойство в качестве аргумента логического оператора js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно в качестве аргумента в логическом операторе использовать css свойство

```
if (sliderItem.style.left == "100%")
```

Доп. инфа

js

```
var sliderItem = document.getElementById("slider_" + sliderCount);

  if (sliderItem.style.left == "100%") {
    alert("Fd")
  }
```

css

```
 #slider_1 {
      left: 100%;
    }
```

html

```
 <li class="slider-item" id="slider_1"></li>
              left: 100%;
            }
```

Простите , не смог нагуглить :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Документация [computedStyleMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap)

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById('slider_1').computedStyleMap().get('left').toString() === '100%'
)
```

```css
#slider_1 {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="slider-item" id="slider_1">foo</li>
```

Для браузеров не поддерживающих computedStyleMap, [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
console.log(
  getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('slider_1')).left === '100%'
)
```

```css
#slider_1 {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="slider-item" id="slider_1">foo</li>
```